# show that if $\mu(A\bigtriangleup A_n)\rightarrow 0$ then $μ(A_n)\rightarrow\mu(A)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, A, µ)$ be a positive metric space. If $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $(A_n)_{(n \in N^*)},A \in X$ 
show that if $\mu(A\bigtriangleup A_n)\rightarrow 0$ then $μ(A_n)\rightarrow\mu(A)$

What I have tried so far is

use that $A\bigtriangleup A_n = (A/A_n)\cup(A_n/A)$ 
and since $(A/A_n)\cap(A_n/A)= \emptyset$ then $\mu(A\bigtriangleup A_n) = \mu(A/A_n)+\mu(A_n/A) \rightarrow 0$ 
now I am trying to contain $μ(A_n)$ in an inequality where both side converge to $A$

EDIT: thanks to Thorgott's point both $\mu(A/A_n)$ and $\mu(A_n/A)$ converge to $0$ and $(A/A_n)\cap A_n = \emptyset$
then $\mu(A) = \mu(A/A_n) + \mu(A_n) \Rightarrow \mu(A_n) \rightarrow0+\mu(A)$

Comment: Note that both terms are positive, so $\mu(A\setminus A_n)$ and $\mu(A_n\setminus A)$ individually go to $0$.

Comment: @Thorgott yeah did not even consider the positivity. I believe the answer is correct now, but I am not sure yet

Comment: You can get this from the answers below, but the key inequality to remember is $$|\mu(A) - \mu(B)| \leq \mu(A \triangle B).$$ Mnemonically, the "triangle" inequality for measures.

Comment: @aduh Could I use that if the measure was not positive but complete? I think yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another useful approach
\begin{align}
\bigl|\mu(A_n)-\mu(A)\bigr|&=\biggl|\int (\mathbb{1}_{A_n}-\mathbb{1}_A)\,d\mu\biggr|\\
&\leq \int|\mathbb{1}_{A_n}-\mathbb{1}_{A}|\,d\mu
\end{align}
Now, by considering all possible options we observe that $|\mathbb{1}_{A_n}-\mathbb{1}_{A}|\leq \mathbb{1}_{A\triangle A_n}$. Hence,
$$\bigl|\mu(A_n)-\mu(A)\bigr|\leq \mu(A\triangle A_n)$$
and the result follows.

Comment: In fact, $|1_{A_n} - 1_A| = 1_{A \triangle A_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\mu(A\Delta A_n)\to 0$ and consequently $\mu\left(A\cap A_{n}^{\complement}\right)\to0$.

Then on base of: $$\mu\left(A\right)=\mu\left(A\cap A_{n}\right)+\mu\left(A\cap A_{n}^{\complement}\right)$$

we conclude that: $$\mu\left(A\cap A_{n}\right)\to\mu\left(A\right)$$

Then on base of: $$\mu\left(A\Delta A_{n}\right)+2\mu\left(A\cap A_{n}\right)=\mu A+\mu A_{n}$$
we find that: $$\mu A_{n}\to\mu A$$